# Describing transformations using base vectors

Tags: matrices, transformation, vectors

So I just learned that we can describe vector transformations of shapes using base vectors, where the base vector I = $$     \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
       \end{pmatrix} $$ and J=$$     \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
       \end{pmatrix}$$

The transformation of I and J by matrix  \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 \\
       \end{pmatrix}

is a clockwise rotation of 90 degrees.

I understand how that's happening. Because if I draw I and J on an xy-axis graph, I can clearly see the points move that way Now I'm supposed to express a reflection in the y-axis, using the help of base vectors.

A reflection in y-axis of base vectors I and J should have them go from (a) to (b) as in the diagram below (with J' superimposing J):

[image]

and so I believe the transformation vector, using the base vectors, should be this:
\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
       \end{pmatrix}

But that's not the case! The correct answer is 
\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 \\
       \end{pmatrix}

How is that so? Why the -1 in the lower right corner? Can someone please explain?

Comment: The question said: "Reflection in y-axis"... doesn't that mean a reflection along the line of x=0?

Comment: http://people.bath.ac.uk/sej20/transform.html according to this website you are correct

Comment: You are correct.  $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ is a reflection in *both* axes, or what is the same, a 180° rotation around the origin.